# WebApi 2 with cors not working, jquery not sending the preflight?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have this in my HttpConfiguration on the webapi.

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*","*");
configuration.EnableCors(cors);
```

and I do my request with:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', url: "http://www.remoteurl.com",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        category: 'test',
        id: 'test',
        version: 'test',
        payload: JSON.stringify({
        'options': {
            imageWidth: 7360,
            imageHeight: 4912,
            InternalCameraParameters: [11349, 0, 0, 0, 11341.35490, 0, 3655, 2456, 1],
            Roll: i.roll() * Math.PI / 180,
            Pitch: i.pitch() * Math.PI / 180,
            Yaw: i.heading() * Math.PI / 180,
            Height: i.height()
        }
    })
})
}).done((data: any[]) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

but when looking in the network tab, it looks like the post is the only request being send. Not option request send first. and then the post is just cancelled:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.remoteurl.com. No 'Access-`Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:19024' is therefore not allowed access.`
```

Comment: Has CORS been enabled on the remote resource  at http://www.remoteurl.com ? Or you just enabled it on your api?

Comment: I found out the problem was with the url not being avalible and also some other parameters of the request that failed.